# typeorm search in relation without using query builder nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I try to search some field in relation using typeorm Here is my UserEntity

```
  @OneToOne(() => UserAuth, userAuth => userAuth.user, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({name:'id'})
  userAuth?: UserAuth;
```

In UserAuthEntity I have

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;
  @Column()
  username: string;
  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user.UserAuth)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user?: UserEntity;
```

example data in database

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | testUser |

In my Query I use

```
this.userRepository.find({
      relations: [ 'userAuth' ],
      where: {
        userAuth: {
          username: 'testUser'
        }
      }
    }); //this one return null data
```

I always get null data but if I change username into id I got right data

```
 this.userRepository.find({
          relations: [ 'userAuth' ],
          where: {
            userAuth: {
              id: 1
            }
          }
        }); // this query return data
```

if I use query builder every work fine but  is their anyway to make this query work ?

Comment: You can use userAuthRepo with relations User, I experienced this sometimes and maybe that's the problem with relation that you can use other properties than id from those related tables.

Comment: can u give me an example @deko_39

Comment: this.userAuthRepo.find({username: 'testUser', relation: ['user']}, )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that find/findOne doesn't allow filtering by nested relation properties.

You should use `QueryBuilder` instead.

Check the example code below:

```js
const username = 'testUser';

await this.ormRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("userEntity")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("userEntity.userAuth", "userAuth")
    .where("userAuth.username= :username", { username })
    .getMany();
```

And you can check more about this issue in this [link reference](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707)